# How to know the source of a commit in Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-log

I would like to know the source of commit of a bitbucket.Whether the file is been edited online directly or via terminal or via source-tree or using any other softwares.

Is it possible to identify that?

Comment: It's not.  Commits are done by the git command, so regardless of the editor, it's always a `git commit` that actually performs the commit.

Comment: Would you please fix the tags? A `git` tag would be very welcome while that `bitbucket-pipelines` tag has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: Still wrong tags. Not related to `git-tag` but to the `git` and `git-log` tags!

Answer (score 0):

You could pay attention to commit authorship metadata. Some people have their workstations or IDEs configured with different author names or emails, e.g. the one their used to register into Bitbucket vs a total foobar they typed after their first local commit failed.

E.g. I'd expect online editions to use the same profile that the commits produced by merging pull-requests.

So, you could potentially issue an organization policy and tell developers to setup artificially distinct name/email in each potential commit source (IDE, git CLI, other git tooling, Bitbucket account)

BUT

This can always be crafted and tampered e.g.

```
GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="Sandeep" GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=sandeep@myorg.com git commit --amend --author "Sandeep <sandeep@myorg.com>"
```

so this approach is 100% unreliable as @lane.maxwell hinted in that comment.

Comment: So this link https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/viewing-log-history-of-a-repository-785615840.html

Comment: @lane.maxwell I was checking and found the above link, Is this reliable or possible?